# Receiving a Segmentation Fault when using this memory allocator

Tags: c, shared-memory

I am trying to implement a memory allocator which can be called by multiple processes at once, so I used shared memory to keep the information of the first and last memory block alocated, both are put in the first 32 bytes of the shared memory and after that I tried to just have a simple allocation from the getpagesize() offset in the shared memory to see if it works but I keep getting a Segmentation Fault when using it to allocate a simple integer variable and I cannot figure out why.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
/* Only for the debug printf */
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>       
#include <fcntl.h>          
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef char ALIGN[16];

union header {
    struct {
        size_t size;
        unsigned is_free;
        union header *next;
    } s;
    /* force the header to be aligned to 16 bytes */
    ALIGN stub;
};
typedef union header header_t;


header_t *get_free_block(size_t size)
{
    char shm_name[] = "memalloc";
    int shm_fd;
    shm_fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    if (shm_fd < 0)
    {
        perror(NULL);
        return NULL;
    }


    size_t shm_size = 10 * getpagesize();
    if (ftruncate(shm_fd, shm_size) == -1)
    {
        perror(NULL);
        shm_unlink(shm_name);
        return NULL;
    }

    char* shm_ptr = mmap(0, shm_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
        if (shm_ptr == MAP_FAILED)
        {
            perror(NULL);
            shm_unlink(shm_name);
            return NULL;
        }

    header_t *head;
    if (shm_ptr)
        head = (header_t*)shm_ptr;
    else
        head = NULL;
    header_t *tail;
    if (head)
        tail = (header_t*)(shm_ptr + 16);
    else
        tail = NULL;
    header_t *curr = head;
    while(curr) {
        /* see if there's a free block that can accomodate requested size */
        if (curr->s.is_free && curr->s.size >= size)
            return curr;
        curr = curr->s.next;
    }
    return NULL;
}


void *malloc(size_t size)
{

    char shm_name[] = "memalloc";
    int shm_fd;
    shm_fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    if (shm_fd < 0)
    {
        perror(NULL);
        return NULL;
    }


    size_t shm_size = 10 * getpagesize();
    if (ftruncate(shm_fd, shm_size) == -1)
    {
        perror(NULL);
        shm_unlink(shm_name);
        return NULL;
    }

    char* shm_ptr = mmap(0, 32, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
        if (shm_ptr == MAP_FAILED)
        {
            perror(NULL);
            shm_unlink(shm_name);
            return NULL;
        }
    header_t *head;
    if (shm_ptr)
        head = (header_t*)shm_ptr;
    else
        head = NULL;
    header_t *tail;
    if (head)
        tail = (header_t*)(shm_ptr + 16);
    else
        tail = NULL;

    size_t total_size;
    void *block;
    header_t *header;
    if (!size)
        return NULL;

    header = get_free_block(size);
    if (header) {
        /* Woah, found a free block to accomodate requested memory. */
        header->s.is_free = 0;

        return (void*)(header + 1);
    }
    /* We need to get memory to fit in the requested block and header from OS. */
    total_size = sizeof(header_t) + size;
    int nr_pagesize = 1;

    block = mmap(0, total_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, nr_pagesize * getpagesize());
    if (block == MAP_FAILED)    
    {
        perror(NULL);
        shm_unlink(shm_name);

        return NULL;

    }
    header = block;
    header->s.size = size;
    header->s.is_free = 0;
    header->s.next = NULL;
    if (!head)
        head = header;
    if (tail)
        tail->s.next = header;
    tail = header;


    return (void*)(header + 1);
}
```

Here is the test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int *x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

The commands I used on terminal are:

```
gcc -o memalloc.so -fPIC -shared memalloc.c
export LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/memalloc.so
gcc helloworld.c -o hello
```

and after compiling the test program I get the Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Why did you [delete your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59552171/receiving-a-segmentation-fault-on-my-memory-allocator) and post it again?

Comment: Please don't delete and repost your questions. If the question needs clarification or other improvements then edit it instead. Editing a question should push it back onto the front page if that's what you're worried about. And you *really* need to learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes in your code.

Comment: I didn't know how it works, thought that getting downvoted for not providing enough information would mean my post wouldn't get seen anymore cause of the downvotes

Comment: `int x = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));` Dont cast, trust the (void*) pointer.. Plus: `x` needs to be a pointer. Plus: dont store pointers in shared memory and expect them to be valid in all attached programs.

Comment: Sorry, it was meant to be a pointer, but the segmentation fault is still there.

Comment: So how should I otherwise keep the memory blocks, if not by a linked list?

Comment: Plus: the size of your struct exceeds 16 bytes.  (and it is poorly aligned; caused by the silly is_free flag) You can build linked lists **without** pointers, use offsets (or indexes, or sizes) instead. This is what fileformats and databases and filesystems do all the time.

Comment: So instead of the next pointer I should have the offset at which the block begins

Comment: Either the offset, or the block number (index). Start by designing your data structure(s), and their layout on disk.

Comment: Also, don't forget to assign space in your data layout for the mutex whose proper use will confer the ability for multiple concurrent processes to safely use your allocator.  And probably for some kind of indication of the current size of the available memory, to provide for expanding the pool.

Comment: I found a library for a named mutex, so it shouldn't be necessary to assign space for it right?

Comment: regarding: `struct 
    {
        size_t size;
        unsigned is_free;
        union header *next;
    } s;`  debuggers need a tag name, not a struct name. Suggest adding a tag name

Comment: in the `main()` test function, strongly suggest removing: `#include <stdlib.h>` and 
`#include <unistd.h>`  Also suggest writing a header file for your `malloc` file and including that header in both files

Comment: regarding: `shm_fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);`  This will be a problem if more than one process is using this function and/or the function is called more than once.  Suggest removing the `O_CREAT` parameter

Comment: per the MAN page, the name of the shared memory should contain a leading `/`

Comment: Can you explain why if the function is called more than once there is a problem?